# is there a way to preload specific images for desktop users only? (excluding mobile users)

Tags: plugins, performance, responsive, wp-head

My website has a few .PNG images animated at the very start of my Contact page.
Those images are a bit heavy (because they have transparent background), so the animation starts with some of them loading during the animation, looking pretty bad.

So, to fix it, I must add this line `<link rel="preload" as="image" href="url-of-the-image.png"/>` to the `<head>`.

To achieve it, I'm using **Snippets plugin**. If I'm not mistaken, the snippet should like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function () { ?>

function my_custom_js() {
    echo '<link rel="preload" as="image" href=href="url-of-the-image.png"/>';
}

<?php } );
```

The thing is that the very same page (my Contact page) is different for mobile devices: it doesn't use those .PNG images because it would be too much loading time for a phone.

This leads to my question: **Is there a way to exclude mobile devices from the preloading tag I must add to the head?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so **I ended up using "prerender" instead of "preload"** because it suited my circumstances (prerender starts rendering target page before the user visits it, in my case it was a better fit because the page I wanted to preload was not the front-page).

For anyone who's interested in knowing about the responsiveness of preloading or prefetching, **the property "media"** is what you're looking for. It should look like this:

```
<link rel="preload" as="image" href="imageURLhere.png" media="(min-width: 768px)"/>
```

...or if you want to target a whole page to pre-render:

```
<link rel="prerender" href="targetPageURL/" media="(min-width: 768px)">
```

This way it should only **preload** or **prerender** if the viewport is within the **media** conditions range.

Hope it helps!
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can use wp_is_mobile() to check whether it is a mobile device or desktop user.

```
<?php if ( wp_is_mobile() ) : ?>
    /* Display and echo mobile specific stuff here */
<?php else : ?>
    /* Display and echo desktop stuff here */
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: How would the final code be considering I have to add it through Snippets Plugin in Wordpress?

(Thanks! Seems like what I need, but my coding skills are bad so I don't know where to insert that piece of code)